# mongodump command with batchsize option

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am trying to do mongodump but the memory of the mongod instance is limited and I am getting into out of memory error error.

`handle-read: pread: failed to read 3060 bytes at offset 32091584: Cannot allocate memory`

I tired to reduce number of parallel collections by using 
numParallelCollections to 1 but still facing same issue please help me